# How many hours in advance can I enter Mumbai airport for an early morning flight?

Tags: airports, check-in, mumbai, bom

As I'm flying at 06:20 from Mumbai, as a holder of the gold star alliance card, how many hours in advance I can be at the airport? Per example may I go at 12 and then go to the lounge.

Because in some airports the check-in starts 2-3 hrs in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the airport itself, or to the part after check-in?

Comment: I'm referring if per example I arrive 4-5 hrs earlier,,,,,if I can do my check in, and then go to the lounge and wait there my flight .

Answer (score 2):

According to my (and my colleagues) experience, the security outside the airports won't let you in before 3 hours. My flight is always at 2:30 am, and I'm forced to book a hotel room to wait it out.